Cache Busting in Angular
Using Angular 14 and Cloudflare for caching. I have started noticing that after every deployment in the production, the page comes black until the caching period is over.
When visiting the built script js file, it gives a 404 page, but after appending a query to the URL, it is working fine
# not working
https://app.scanova.io/runtime.4bc2f68e0b409d29.js

# Working
https://app.scanova.io/runtime.4bc2f68e0b409d29.js?v9.0.1

I tried checking generating build after making changes to the file but the file name generated is always the same

Also tried passing --output-hashing all to the build command but the file names are still the same.
One way to implement Cache Businting is by appending query parameters to build every time but is there any angular way to do it?

Edit 2

Setup new Angular 17 project and following is the angular.json content.
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "example-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/example-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "@toast-ui/editor-plugin-chart",
              "@toast-ui/editor-plugin-color-syntax",
              "@toast-ui/editor-plugin-uml"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "2mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "5kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": {
                "scripts": true
              }
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "example-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "example-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "example-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Using ng build to build the project. And here are the screenshots of the build generated by changing the version number to 0.0.1, 1.0.1, and 1.0.2 respectively.



The file names of main.xxx.js, runtime and polyfills files are the same.

you should use ng build --aot --configuration production instead of ng build

I tried the above command as well, however cannot see any change in any of the files except runtime. But this only changed once. After changing the version and re-running the above command generates the same file name.

Also with the above command, after Angular 9+ aot is default set to true, and the default configuration is set to production.

ah true, missed the defaultConfiguration.
Anyway I suppose the hashing is based in the outputted files, so if the file content doesn't changes, the name stays the same.
but if you change someting i.e. in AppComponent the name will be different.
I portant is that you explicitly don't cache the index.html file

change the "version" in package.json before building.
This will cause the runtime.js file to get a new name.

I tried this as well, but the file names are still the same. We do semantic versioning and update the package.json file on every release.

this is stange, I just tested this with this command ng build --output-path=dist --aot --configuration production and the filename changes when I change the version.
What build command do you use?

maybe it's because I have "outputHashing": "all" in angular.json production configurations, but you do that as well... so idk...

Please check Edit 2 in the question. I have added the build screenshot by changing version number along with the content of angular.json.
